# Kendodropdownlist success method

Tags: kendo-ui

I have the following code

```
    $("#categories").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        dataSource: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetNames", "Index")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST"
                }
            }
        }
    }).data("kendoDropDownList");
```

I need to execute some code after the dropdownlist is bound with the data. How can I achieve this.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use [`dataBound`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/dropdownlist#databound) event on `kendoDropDownList`?

Comment: I was looking for a success event however dataBound event works too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#categories").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "Name",
    dataValueField: "ID",
    dataSource: {
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: '@Url.Action("GetNames", "Index")',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            }
        }
    },
    dataBound: OnDataBound
    }).data("kendoDropDownList");

function OnDataBound() {
// do stuff
}
```